# I need to compare strings in an array and store/return the longest word

Tags: java, arrays, string

I cannot figure out what to do.  I keep getting an error because the array exceeds the bounds but I am not sure why.  This is the latest instance of the code there have been many attempts.

```
private static String compareWords(String[] words) {
    String longestWord = words[0];
    for (int i = 0; i <= words.length; i ++){
        while (longestWord.length()< words[i].length()){
            longestWord=words[i];                
        }
    }                
    return longestWord;
}
```

Comment: This isn't JavaScript

Comment: Its being written javamain class thats one of my methods.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your post isn't javascript, but here's basically what you want to do. It should be easy to change it over from javascript.

```
function compareWords(words){
  var longestWord = '';
  for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
    if(words[i].length > longestWord.length){
      longestWord = words[i];
    }
  }
  return longestWord;
}
var words = ['gunslinger', 'gundam', 'dragon', 'shirt', 'unicorn', 'internationalization'];
compareWords(words);
```

Comment: This worked thank you!

Comment: @JackSchirtz Make up your mind. Is it Java or JavaScript?

Comment: It was/is Java, I should have said that after I modified it, the code worked.  I was wrong with my >= sign.